# which command to execute to run multiple OLAP queries?

Tags: postgresql, parallelism, performance, performance-testing

I have 10 sql files that contains different OLAP queries.

I want to run them as a batch. Meaning by batch, Postgres will consider each file as a batch and execute the queries at once (depends on its own managing process)

The follow command, execute each query one by one

```
psql -h localhost -d databasename -U user -p port -a -q -f input.sql -o output.txt
```

Is that possible ? and how to calculate the time it takes to execute that batch sql queries ?

Comment: A single connection can only run one statement at a time. And `psql` only uses a single connection. If you want to run them in parallel you need to start `psql` multiple times each instance with one statement

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so i run psql q1, psql q2 .. or you mean another command ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use i.e. [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) which provides possibility to run arbitrary commands/programs at the same time, the syntax would be something like:

```
parallel psql -h localhost -d databasename -U user -p port -a -q -f input{}.sql -o output{}.txt ::: 1 2
```

this command will execute 2 queries located in `input1.sql` and `input2.sql` at the same time.

Another option would be going for a dedicated load testing tool like [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), if you add [Postgres JDBC Driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you will be able to provide your connection details under [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) and the query(ies) in the [JDBC Request Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request). Check out [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter/) article for more details if needed.

Then you can increase the number of threads in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and JMeter will execute the queries according to your workload model. You will be able to observe performance metrics either using [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) or via [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html). This way you will get more comprehensive results and be able to correlate increasing number of concurrent threads with increased queries execution time, identify saturation points, bottlenecks, etc.